# Let $V$ a vector space of finite dimension. If $ I_V:V\rightarrow V$ is the identity operator, prove $(I_V)^*=I_{V^*}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space of finite dimension.

> If $I_v:V\rightarrow V$ is the identity operator, prove $(I_V)^*=I_{V^*}$

Note: $V^*=\{f\mid f:V\rightarrow \mathbb{K}\}$

I don't have idea of how to solve this, can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 3):

$(I_V)^*$ is a map from $V^*$ to $V^*$, just like $I_V$. Now use the definition of $(I_V)^*$.

For $f \in V^*$ we have:

$$(I_V)^*(f) = f \circ I_V = f = I_{V^*}(f)$$

We conclude $(I_V)^* = I_{V^*}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\left<w,(I_{V})^{\ast}u^{\ast}\right>=\left<I_{V}w,u^{\ast}\right>=\left<w,u^{\ast}\right>=\left<w,I_{V^{\ast}}u^{\ast}\right>$, here $u^{\ast}\in V^{\ast}$, $w\in V$.